Question about Regular singular points

Given this definition of regular singular points, I am unsure why only checking the limit is finite is sufficient. I know that if the limit exists, the function can be made to exist but this doesn't say anything about the derivatives. How do I know that $(x-x_0)*\frac{Q(x)}{P(x)}$ or $(x-x_0)^2\frac{R(x)}{P(x)}$ are analytic at $x_0$ then?

You are considering the situation where $P,Q,R$ are polynomials. You get clean factorizations and the usual facts about quotients of polynomials or, in general, power series.

so in other words, the limit of the derivatives at that point also exists? How can I know for sure though?

Because you can compute the power series by polynomial division. Likewise you can also prove that the radius of convergence is positive, it is the distance to the nearest root of the denominator. In the case of power series it is the smallest of that and the radii of denominator and numerator. So the minimum of a finite number of positive numbers is still positive.
